# Finding the moments for a thin wire along a semicircle

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

> Find $M_x$ and $M_y$ for a thin wire along the semicircle $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Take $\rho=1$ so $M=\text{length}=\pi$.

Here, $M_x$ and $M_y$ are moments in the x-axis and y-axis, respectively. $M$ is the mass.

I know how to find them if it were a semicircle disk:
$$M_x=\int_0^12y\sqrt{1-y^2}\;dy=\frac23$$
$$M_y=\int_{-1}^1x\sqrt{1-x^2}\;dx=0$$

But now I cannot figure out what $x(y)$ and $y(x)$ are:
$$M_x=\int y\;x(y)\;dy$$
$$M_y=\int x\;y(x)\;dx$$

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Parametrise the wire by $(x,y)=(\cos t,\sin t)$, $0\le t\le\pi$. The
$x$-moment is zero, by symmetry. The $y$ moment is got by integrating $y$
over the wire and  is
$$\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi y\,dt=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi \sin t\,dt=\cdots.$$

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I think the y-moment should be zero because it includes the distance from the y-axis (but maybe this is just a matter of convention). Using your approach (parametrization), the x-moment would be $\int_0^\pi\sin t\;dt=\left.-\cos t\right|_0^\pi=2$. We can check the y-moment: $\int_0^\pi\cos t\;dt=\left.\sin t\right|_0^\pi=0$. Dividing by the mass $\pi$ would give the center of mass.